# Proving the Mean Value Theorem Without Rolle's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions, alternative-proof

Can someone point me to a proof of the mean value theorem that doesn't directly utilize the results of Rolle's theorem?

Comment: You can use Cauchy's mean value theorem to proove the Mean Value theorm, but thats just silly. Why would anyone not use Rolle's theorm here? (you could also just proove Rolle's, and then MVT...)

Comment: In any "big picture" of mathematics Rolle and MVT are indistinguishable: Rolle is a special case of MVT, and MVT a trivial application of Rolle - no new mathematics is needed to pass from one to the other.

Comment: I am only trying to satisfy a curiosity. I am sure there exists a way to prove MVT without first having to prove Rolle's as a lemma. If the answer is "no" then that would be interesting. If the answer is "yes' then that would also be interesting. I do understand the equivalence between Rolle's and MVT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Curiosity is awesome and definitely welcomed in maths :)

Let $f \in C^1([a,b], \mathbb{R})$. The Mean Value Theorem asserts the equality $f(b)-f(a) = f'(c)(b-a)$ for some $c \in [a, b]$. Equivalently,

$$
f(b)-f(a) - f'(c)(b-a) = 0.
$$

Let

$$
h(x) := f(b)-f(a) - f'(x)(b-a).
$$

The "standard" argument is to say that, unless $h(a)=0$ or $h(b)=0$, this is equivalent to looking for a (local) extremum $c \in (a, b)$ of the function $x \mapsto (f(b)-f(a))x - f(x)(b-a)$. Indeed, the latter function's derivative is precisely $h$ so then we obtain $h(c) = 0$ as desired. As you pointed out, this is achieved via Rolle's Theorem.

However, one does not need to formulate the problem as an instance of Rolle's Theorem. A more direct proof would only involve $h$. It is easy to show that:

**Lemma**: If $f \in C([a, b], \mathbb{R})$ and $f$ is differentiable in $(a, b)$ such that $m \le f'(x) \le M$ for all $x \in (a, b)$. Then, $m(b-a) \le f(b) -f(a) \le M(b-a)$.

*A fortiori*, a function $f \in C^1([a,b], \mathbb{R})$ satisfies the above lemma's hypothesis. Then, for all $x \in [a, b]$

$$
(m - M)(b-a) \le h(x) \le (M-m)(b-a)
$$

Since $(m-M)(b-a) \le 0$ and $(M-m)(b-a) \ge 0$, the Intermediate Value Theorem applied to $h(x)$ shows that there exists $c \in [a, b]$ such that $h(c) = 0$ as desired.

**EDIT**: the assumption $f \in C^1([a, b], \mathbb{R})$ can be relaxed. Indeed, Darboux's Theorem tells us that if $f \in C([a, b], \mathbb{R})$ is differentiable then for all $y \in [f'(a), f'(b)]$, there exists $c \in (a, b)$ such that $f'(c) = y$.

Therefore, since $0 \in [(m-M)(b-a), (M-m)(b-a)]$, there exists $c \in (a, b)$ such that $h(c) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you so much :)